# Router lazy loading

Tags: python, routes

I'm using wheezy web framework, but I'm guessing the same concept can be applied to any framework out there.

I have my urls in a list:

```
import WelcomeHandler
import OtherHandler

all_urls = [
    url('/', WelcomeHandler, name='HomePage'),
    url('/some-other-page', OtherHandler, name='OtherPage'),
    ...
]
```

To make this work, I would need to import all Request Handlers into the file. If you have many pages, these imports can start to get out of control aside from the fact that you have many imports in a file which clutters it up and I'm guessing performance-wise it's not the best solution.

What's the common approach to lazy-import these Request Handlers? WebApp2 framework for example allows you to specify them as strings with dot notation and evaluates that to the actual file: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#lazy-handlers

From the documentation, it looks like wheezy web does not have this option. How could I implement something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with wheezy but if all you have to do is call `url()` and add it to a list, my approach would be an `install` method inside your handler modules:

```
from importmodule import all_urls

...
install("HomePage", "/", WelcomeHandler)    

def install(name, path, callable):
    all_urls.append(url(path, callable, name=name))
```